# Bitmap turns into colored background

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here is my code:

```
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    Path path=new Path();
    path.moveTo(150, 10);
    path.lineTo(200, 40);
    path.lineTo(200, 120);
    path.lineTo(160, 150);
    path.lineTo(100, 150);
    path.lineTo(60, 120);
    path.lineTo(60, 40);
    path.lineTo(100, 10);
    path.close();
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, 0, 0, null)
```

Here is my screenshot link

http://postimg.org/image/kfv7rfqo1/23108b08/

I want to achieve left image in shape of right image as i have tried but it shows me result as in screenshot.

Comment: what do you mean by in shape of right image, do you want to put it in the middle of the shape ?

Comment: Actually i want to turn my actual image in hexagonal shape as in above URL so i have used above code to do it. As result, i achieved hexagonal shape but image's background turns black rather than original image.